# a simple real-time-clock driver program not getting output

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module, real-time-clock

I wrote a driver program which will interact with RTC and gives the time.

program is:

```
    outb(GET_HR, CMD_REG);
    hrs = inb(STAT_REG);

    outb(GET_MIN, CMD_REG);
    min = inb(STAT_REG);

    pr_info("time: hrs:min\n", hrs, min);
```

Its working, but giving in format of GMT. I want my local time(GMT+5.30). I explicitly added 5:30 in the program. some times its not giving correct time. Is there any implicit function to get local time?

Answer (score 0):

it is not task of the kernel to do time conversions.  You should always work with UTC times in kernel and translate them in userspace to localtime.